# Leap year approximation algorithm question

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms

I've been looking at the wikipedia page on [leap years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year), and it states there that the average number of days per year is $365+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{100}+\frac{1}{400}$. If I am not mistaken the rule for if a year number $m$ corresponds to a leap year is:

- If $m(mod4)=0$ but $m(mod100)\neq 0$, then is a leap year.
- If $m(mod100)=0$ but $m(mod400)\neq 0$, then is not a leap year.
- if $m(mod400)=0$ then is a leap year.

If this is indeed the case, then can we say that the indicator function of the set of leap years, which I'll denote by $L$, is:

$$ \mathbf{1}_L(m)=\mathbf{1}_{4\mathbb{N}}(m)-\mathbf{1}_{100\mathbb{N}}(m)+\mathbf{1}_{400\mathbb{N}}(m).  $$

Is the reasoning thus far is correct? And if so can we say in general that should a celestial body exist whose average number of day per year is

$$ N+ \sum\limits_{k=1}^\ell \frac{(-1)^{s_k}}{q_k} $$

where $N,q_1,...,q_\ell\in \mathbb{N}$, and $\{ s_k \}\subseteq\{0,1\}$ such that $ 0<\sum\limits_{k=1}^\ell \frac{(-1)^{s_k}}{q_k}<1 $, then its leap year set $L'$ would satisfy

$$ \mathbf{1}_{L'}(m)= \sum\limits_{k=1}^\ell (-1)^{s_k} \cdot \mathbf{1}_{q_k\mathbb{N}} \;? $$

Also would the cycle of the leap years be $h(q_1,...,q_\ell)=lcm(q_1,...,q_\ell)$, and the number of leap years in such a cycle be

$$ h(q_1,...,q_\ell) \cdot \sum\limits_{k=1}^\ell \frac{(-1)^{s_k}}{q_k}?$$

I'm trying to understand the algorithm by which leap years are determined, and this is what I suspect thus far.

Comment: Correct, except that the cycle of leap years repeats every $lcm(q_i)$.

Comment: @Chrystomath So if we change $h(q_1,...,q_\ell)$ to $lcm(q_1,..,q_\ell)$, would it work then?

Comment: Shouldn't there be an $N$ in that formula?

Comment: @Chrystomath Well I think that for a leap year the fractional part would only matter. Same as how the number $365$ does not appear for a regular leap year.

Comment: Note also that for the earth as a "celestial body", the underlying point is that periods of revolution (days) and orbital periods (years) don't sync, i.e. a year is about 365.24219.. days, and the Gregorian leap year rule is just an apprximation. In addition, the length of a day changes over time. So the "leap year rule" is a property of the calendar, not of the celestial body.

Comment: @Toffomat I am aware that this an approximation, but I was trying to understand the leap year algorithm in general. I assume they decided that was an adequate approximation.

Comment: Yes, agreed. I was thinking of the total number of days.

Comment: As that Wikipedia article mentions, an 8/33 leap year system is slightly more accurate, but the pattern of leap years is a bit messier. FWIW, the current Gregorian system has an excess of 1 leap year in about 3222 years. So we could deal with that by extending the rule (using your notation) to $365+\frac1{4}-\frac1{100}+\frac1{400}-\frac1{3200}$. The next term in that series is $+\frac1{144×3200}$, but by then the mean solar day length will be noticeably longer than 86400 seconds. But I guess the people of the future can worry about that. ;)